# How to get system date and time instead of internet's PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a website which reserves lot for clients. Lot reserved has expiration date. In localhost, everything works fine. The system date and time is what my website is getting. But when I tested it online (I uploaded my website) it's not getting the system date and time.

```
$d = date('d M Y h:i A'); //TODAYS DATE---> this doesnt change when I change my PC's date and time

$curdate = strtotime($d)*1000;
echo $d;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM reservation";
$res = $conn->query($sql);

foreach ($res as $row) {
    $exp = strtotime($row['expiration'])*1000;
    $lot = $row['lot'];
    $sqli = "SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE ".$curdate." >= ".$exp." AND status='reserved'";
    $resu = $conn->query($sqli);
    foreach ($resu as $ro) {
        $id = $ro['reserve_id'];
        $sl = "DELETE FROM reservation WHERE reserve_id='$id'";
        $conn->query($sl);
        $l = substr($ro['lot'], 1);
        echo "<script>$(document).find('#_".$l."').css({'fill':'#848484'});</script>";
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the error??

Comment: Of course it gets the servers date and time. That's where it runs. Why should it use any other time?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen is there a way I can get system date and time instead of server?

Comment: php will always get server time

Comment: No however, you can save it as gmt time and convert it later.

Answer (score 0):

PHP uses the time for the machine it's running on "Server", still you can get the time from the client machine using javascript/jquery -ajax call like :

```
var TimeNow = new Date();
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    data : {date : TimeNow}
});
```